# cant call a javascript function within jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used two jqueries library

```
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have a function named `onSubmit();`

```
   function onSubmit() 

     {if ($.trim($("#password").val()) != "") {
           $("#Command").val("LOGIN");
          }
     }
```

When I try to use `onSubmit` function, intelicense in visual studio find it without any problem, but at run time I get error `undefined onSubmit`.
I try to use `onSubmit` function within this piece of code:

```
$(function () {
$("#slider").draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: 'parent',
    drag: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left > 550) {
            $("#well").fadeOut();
            onSubmit(); //this line get undefined error
        } else {
             ("opacity", 100 - (ui.position.left / 5))
        }
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.position.left < 551) {
            $(this).animate({
                left: 0
            })
        }
    }
});
```

I declared onSubmit function at bottom of my codes after everythings. Im not sure if it cause problem.

UPDATE: I changed my declaration like this:

```
   window.onSubmit()= function() {
       if ($.trim($("#password").val()) != "") {
           $("#Command").val("LOGIN");
       }
    }
```

Comment: How/where is `onSubmit` defined? Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Try to load the <file_name>.js where onSubmit() is defined, before including `jquery-ui.min.js`. May be thats causing problem...

Comment: @ArtjomB. there is nothing in separate places. every things are gathered in same place but i wrote function onSubmit() after second part of code that i mentioned above. Should i declare onSubmit somehow first?

Comment: @saeed No, the ordering is irrelevant, because you execute it on page load. I asked in which scope it is defined which is what bgoldst answered

Comment: could try by changing `$(function () {.. }` to `$(document.ready(function () {..})`..

Comment: It looks like you are having a scope issue here, the `undefined onSubmit` is a good indication that **onSubmit is not defined in the same scope as it is called from.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript functions are defined within their containing scope. If the function definition occurs inside another function, then it will only be defined inside that function, and won't be accessible elsewhere. If a function is defined outside of any function, then it will be defined globally, which is equivalent to residing on the `window` object.

You can explicitly make a function global by assigning it directly on the `window` object:

```
window.onSubmit = function() { ... };
```

Note that you should include the trailing semicolon in this case because the assignment is an expression; the function definition is said to be "expressionized", and so the statement must be terminated by a semicolon.

If a function is defined globally then it will be accessible to all code, regardless of scope.

Comment: I updated my quesion, but I still have problem. May you check my update please?

Comment: Remove the parentheses after `onSubmit`, they're syntactically incorrect. `window.onSubmit` is three tokens that together say "the `onSubmit` property of the `window` object", which which is being used as an lvalue in the assignment.

Comment: Ironically, I just realized I forgot the parentheses after the `function` keyword in the code in my answer, which are syntactically required. I've now updated it to include them. Sorry about that.

Comment: One little general point: Artjom B. said that it doesn't matter where a function is defined as long as it's in the right scope. That's only true if you use the `function myFunction() { ...` syntax. If you write `myFunction = function() { ...` as in this answer, then it can matter. But not in this case, since it doesn't actually try to call the function until a drag event is fired.